# Finding a polynomial that interpolates data (Newton's method with Horner's method)

Tags: numerical-methods

**Problem** Find the polynomial that interpolates the data:
$$
\begin{array}{|c||c|c|}
\hline x & 3 & 7 \\
\hline y & 5 & -1
\end{array}
$$

---

So I have Newton's polynomials given by
$$
p_{0}(x)=c_{0}, \quad p_{i}(x)=p_{i-1}(x)+c_{i} \prod_{j=0}^{i-1}\left(x-x_{j}\right), \quad i=0, \ldots, n
$$

and the constants $c_i,i=0,...,n$ are given by
$$
c_{i}=\frac{\left(y_{i}-p_{i-1}\left(x_{i}\right)\right)}{\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)}
$$

In general we have $n+1$ data points. In my case I have $n+1=2$ data points. The resulting polynomial form the interpolation will be of degree $n$,  right?

Which part of this entire method is Newton's method for interpolation and which part is Horner's method for calculating the polynomials $p_i$ ?

Comment: It is presented confusing, because I'm confused. I do not understand it. I think the problem is asking to find the interpolation polynomial using newton's method. 
What is horners form?

Comment: Alright, I can't see what that has to do with this problem. @moo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, $p$ forms the [Newton polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial), which is just one way to write/find a [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

[Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is a special way of writing polynomials which allows for more efficient evaluation. In the the particular case of Newton polynomials, one may write the solution in the form

$$c_0+(x-x_0)(c_1+(x-x_1)(c_2+\dots))$$

which allows one to avoid evaluating lots of products (repeated calculation of $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\dots$).

Comment: Okay. When finding the Newton polynomial, when should I stop the algorithm?

Comment: You use the given points like you said. Or, to be more precise, you take a number of points that are near the area you would like to estimate best and ignore points farther away.

Comment: From my problem the $p$ will be $p_1$, right?

Comment: If you wish to use both points, then yes you will end up with $p_1$.

Comment: oh! Now get it thanks!

Comment: The resultat polynomial will $p=p_n$ will always have $\deg(p) \leq n$, right?

Comment: If you have $n+1$ points, then the highest degree polynomial you can use is $p_n$. Like I pointed out in the comment above, you don't necessarily always want to use this, but you can.

Comment: Okay, so if I use all $n+1$ points, then the polynomial $p=p_n$  will be of degree $n$, right? 
If a point is an outliner and I want to ignorer that, then I have $n$ points and the resulting polynomial will be $p=p_{n-1}$ and the degree of this will be $n-1$? 
Right?

Comment: Degree of at most $n-1$ yes.

Comment: I do not get, what it is at most $n-1$. Could you explain that?

Comment: The degree depends on the last *nonzero* coefficient. If $c_n$ is nonzero then the degree is $n-1$, but otherwise...

Comment: Right, right. I think I get it know. Thanks.